# A way to assign the elements of one list to another list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Essentially what im trying to do with this code is a quiz. I've made 2 lists, one with the questions another with the answers. I'm not exactly sure if theres a way to check the index of the randomly chosen question with the index of the where the answer is.

here are the two lists and the most relevant code to what im trying here.

```
questions = ["What is an example of a topology?: ", "What is the best topology for a large network?: ", "What does the '#' do in python?: ", "What is the '%' of this operator in python?: ","What is the most efficient searching algorithm?: ","What is a LAN?: "]

answers = ["Mesh","Star","Comment","Modulus", "Merge","Local Area Network"]


while play == True:
  question = choice(questions)
  print(question)
  x = (questions.index(question))
  y = 
  
  answer = input(" ")
```

As you can probably tell, i got a little confused with comparing the index of the question to the answer, so stopped there and looked for help. Any ideas?

Comment: Use a better data structure to keep questions and answers together, e.g. `[('Question 1 ...', 'Answer 1...'), ('Q2...', 'A2...'), ...]`, or `[{'question': '...', 'answer': '...'}, ...]`.

Comment: In addition to @deceze 's comment, you could then use **tuple unpacking**: `for q,a in my_list: ...` to iterate over the items in the list while making the current question (`q`) and answer (`a`) readily available.

Comment: You can get random question and answer pair using existing lists by: `question, answer = choice(list(zip(questions, answers)))`

Comment: @DarrylG I'm not sure building a list from scratch is a good thing if you only want to select a random element, am I wrong?

Comment: @RiccardoBucco--what you actually would do is `questions_answers = list(zip(questions, answers)); questions_answers = choices(questions_answers, k = len(questions_answers));` to get a random tuples of questions and answers.  Now you can loop through questions_answers.  Problem with using choice is some questions may be asked multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose a random index and then use it to get your question/answer:

```
index = choice(range(len(questions)))
question = questions[index]
answer = answers[index]
```

You could also use `random.randint` (instead of `random.choice`):

```
index = randint(0, len(questions) - 1)
```

`random.randrange` is another option:

```
index = randrange(len(questions))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this first by combining the answers and questions to one nested list for simplicity, But I will post for you both scenarios.

First combine the lists

```
quiz_list = [[i, x] for i,x in zip(questions,answers)]
```

Then run your while loop

```
while True:

   question  = random.choice(quiz_list)
   print(question[0])
   user_answer = input("Your Answer:")

   if user_answer.lower() == question[1].lower():
      print("Congratulations! You got it right")
   else:
      print("Wrong Answer! Try again")
```

If you want to run  with both lists use the index assuming they will not shuffle or sort for whatever reason.

```
while True:

  question  = random.choice(questions)
  print(question)
  user_answer = input("Your Answer:")

  if user_answer.lower() == answers[questions.index(question)].lower():
    print("Congratulations! You got it right")
  else:
    print("Wrong Answer! Try again")
```

**questions.index(question)** Returns the index of the question

**Note:** I convert both the user answer and list answer to lowercase for better comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `zip` to link questions and answers and form a Question Bank:

```
...
qbank = list(zip(questions, answers))
while play == True:
    question, correct_answer = choice(qbank)
    input_answer = input(" ")
...
```

The `qbank` obj will be a list of tuples of form (question, answer), so the multiple assignment in the loop is just doing a random choice from this list, and giving you the question answer pair. You can then compare the `correct_answer` with `the input_answer` to see if the user got it right.